# Power BI SDK don't get or set filters when "all filters" is selected on online report

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to set dynamically filters from JS using Power BI SDK.

When I check on Power BI service the filters to "select all"

[image]

then in my JS code  get filters as bellow

```
rapport.getFilters().then(data => {
  console.log("filters data", data)
  ....
```

I'm getting an empty array :

[image]

Secondly when I try to set filter using setFilters API nothing happens

```
report.setFilters(filters)
```

Here's what I send in 'filters'

[image]

My code works only in one case:

When I go to power bi service and uncheck selectAll then check manually one by one the filters.

[image]

In this case , when I `setFilters` the embedded view is getting updated.
But in my case I'm generating reports automatically so I can't go to PBI online and check every filter, I should keep default "select all" checked and set filter from front-end.

Any solution to set filters programmatically with default checked "selected all " ?

Answer (score 3):

The response you are getting by using getFilters() seems correct.
To set filters programmatically with default checked as "Select all", Please use below code.

```js
// Create a filter
const filter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    target: {
        table: "<TABLE-NAME>",
        column: "<COLUMN-NAME>"
    },
    operator: "All",
    values: []
};
```

```js
// It is recommended to use the updateFilters API to apply filters
report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [filter]);
```

For more info about creating and applying filters, refer the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters)

Comment: I tried using `updateFilters` since you mentioned it's the recommended way but I only see `setFilters`. I'm using powerbi-client 2.11.0. Is this available in recent versions?

Comment: Answering my own question, looks like this api was added this Jan (2021): https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/ce34d4cf84adc48b2e958a4d1dab68bce58e7cf0/dist/powerbi-client.d.ts